# how to explain domain specific constraints to mypy

Tags: python, mypy

Given this snippet:

```
from typing import Dict

def a(my_dict: Dict[str,int])->int:
    return my_dict.get('a') or my_dict.get('b')
```

I know from the domain knowledge that there myust be either a or b key,which mypy cannot know. Therefore i get an error

> error: Incompatible return value type (got Optional[int], expected int)

How can i tell mypy this fact?

my task is to add to an existing python codebase type hinting, therefore i would prefer not to change code, just to add type annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dict.get(...)` method is typed to have a return type of `Optional[ValueType]`. There really isn't a way of working around this fact.

If you know for a fact that your call to `my_dict.get('b')` will always succeed, you can replace it with `my_dict['b']`, which has a return type of just `ValueType`. So, do:

```
from typing import Dict

def a(my_dict: Dict[str, int]) -> int:
    return my_dict.get('a') or my_dict['b']
```

Mypy also understands asserts (to some degree):

```
from typing import Dict

def a(my_dict: Dict[str, int]) -> int:
    ret_val = my_dict.get('a') or my_dict['b']
    assert ret_val is not None
    return ret_val
```

Alternatively, you can add a cast to force mypy to assume your expression has a certain type. This, however, would be the least type-safe option: you're basically overriding what the type checker thinks is correct. This is fine if you're absolutely certain the cast will succeed, but I think the better option is to either restructure your code or at the very least add a runtime check, like we did with the assert above.

```
from typing import Dict, cast

def a(my_dict: Dict[str, int]) -> int:
    return cast(int, my_dict.get('a') or my_dict.get('b'))
```